# print variable inside function inside render with moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I hava a component with this render:

I have the function moment (moment.js library) to print the date, but i get 'invalid date'

```
render() {
  let date = '20150201';
  return (
    <div> {moment({date},'YYYYMMDD').format("DD MM YYYY")}</td>
```

but if send the strin directly on the function:

```
{moment('20150201','YYYYMMDD')
```

it's works; what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: use this: `{moment(date,'YYYYMMDD').format("DD MM YYYY")}`, `{}` around date is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `{}` brackets from `date` variable

```
<div> {moment(date,'YYYYMMDD').format("DD MM YYYY")}</td>
```